# addeventlistener returning function

Tags: javascript, events

i have an onkeypress event in my html code which looks like this, it works as intended

```
<input class="Eingabefeld "type="text" id="valueTwo" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

i wanted to change it to addeventlistener, so after some research i came up with this, but it doesnt work

```
document.getElementById("valueTwo").addEventListener("keypress",validate);

function validate (event){
  var result = isNumber(event);
  return result;
}
```

after some answers, i need to rephrase my question a, i know there are some work arounds, but i specifically would like to know how i can make this function :

```
function isNumber(evt) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
```

}

work with the evenlistener, which works perfectly fine as onclick, i just cant get the syntax right, and im very interested to know what the right syntax would be to make this work, so i get a better understanding of how i can use function returns in conjunction with the event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a value out of an `onxyz`-style attribute is the old way of telling the browser whether to allow or prevent the *default action* of the event. The equivalent with DOM2 event handlers (`addEventListener`) is to call the `preventDefault` method on the event object if you want to prevent the default action:

```
document.getElementById("valueTwo").addEventListener("keypress",validate);
function validate(event){
  if (!isNumber(event)) {
     event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Note that you need to update `isNumber` to return a truthy value if the event is okay (since your current version returns `false` if not okay and `undefined` if okay, both of which are falsy values):

```
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Although if you **had** to keep `isNumber` the way it currently is, you could use:

```
function validate(event){
  if (isNumber(event) === false) {
     event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

...but I wouldn't.

More about the event object [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Example:

```js
function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function validate(event) {
  if (!isNumber(event)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
document.getElementById("valueTwoNew").addEventListener("keypress", validate);
```

```html
<div>Your way:</div>
<input class="Eingabefeld " type="text" id="valueTwo" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<div><code>addEventListener</code></div>
<input class="Eingabefeld " type="text" id="valueTwoNew" />
```

Comment: doesnt work, i reiterated my question and added the isNumber function for better understanding what and why i want to make this work this specific way

Comment: to clarify, it doesnt accept any input now, i have no idea why this happens, you have an idea about this behaviour?

Comment: @Moorli: I didn't notice that `isNumber` only explicitly returns `false`, never `true`. I've updated the above.

Comment: thx a lot it works, i think i understand, so by adding return true, we avoid checking for false the way you set up the expression, and if its false its undefined and nothing happens? im just wondering why return false, doesnt equal prevent.default.

Comment: ok no more elobaration needed, return false isnt a feature of addeventlistener, thats why it works with onclick and not with listener